# How to check if an array is filled with zeros in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, is-empty

So, I have an array in C++ of length `n` and I want to know if it contains at least one positive number. I know for sure that the array contains only non-negative numbers.

I know how to do that but I wonder if there's a more efficient or prettier method than for-loop over the array.

I have something like this:

```cpp
bool is_empty = true;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(arr[i] > 0) {
            is_empty = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only way to avoid iterating over the array is if you have extra information about the position of the elements in the array, for example if it is sorted.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? Without seeing your attempt, it's hard to say what'd be more or less "efficient." Also, is there a reason you're trying to make this more "efficient?" Is it too slow as is and that's causing issues?

Comment: Without any other information of the given array, the efficiency cannot be improved over for-loop over it.

Comment: Ok, sorry for lack of information. I updated this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use a `for` loop, use a [standard algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) instead, for example:

[`std::find_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

int arr[] = ...;
int n = ...;

auto end = arr + n;
if (std::find_if(arr, end, [](int i){ return i > 0; }) != end)
{
    ...
}
```

[`std::any_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

int arr[] = ...;
int n = ...;

if (std::any_of(arr, arr + n, [](int i){ return i > 0; }))
{
    ...
}
```

[`std::none_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

int arr[] = ...;
int n = ...;

if (std::none_of(arr, arr + n, [](int i){ return i == 0; }))
{
    ...
}
```